# Embedding Wordfaire into Self Hosted Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get Wordfaire live blogging embed code to work on my site and having some problems. I created a new page for my live blog feed on site site and added the embed code to the html page in wordpress. When I test it out and try a test live blog nothing runs on the page.

Is there a trick to getting it to work on wordpress??

Thanks in advance to anyone that can assist!

Comment: This will depend on where you would like to have your live blog to be displayed. Do you want this on a specific WordPress page?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are using the HTML view of the WordPress editor to paste the embed code, correct?

A better way would be to make a simple plugin that will create a shortcode with the embed code, then you use that shortcode to display the embed code on your page.

#### Example:

embed-shortcode-plugin.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Plugin Name
Plugin URI: http://pluginurl.com
Description: Plugin description
Version: 1.0
Author: Author Name
Author URI: http://authorurl.com
*/

function embed_shortcode($atts,$content=null){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('optionname'=>'defaultvalue'),$atts));
    // The extract() function above will allow you to do [shortcode optionname="defaultvalue"] in your pages and use $optionname to get the value below
    // The extract() line is optional and can be removed
    // $optionname = defaultvalue
    return 'put your embed code here';
}
add_shortcode('shortcode','embed_shortcode');
// This will add the shortcode 'shortcode': [shortcode], change to whatever

?>
```

Put that in your plugins folder and then activate it. Alternatively, you could remove the stuff between the /* and */ and put that code right in your theme's `functions.php` file and it will run the same.